# set min height of textfiled in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a textfiled in container, and i want the textfiled support multiline, so i can not the the height of the container. but how to set the default height of the textfield when there is no word? 
[image]
[image]
I have try the contentPadding, but not work.
here is my code:

```
TextField(
                              controller: _textEditingController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "留下你的评论吧~",
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: getMyWidth(10), right: getMyWidth(10)),
                                fillColor: default_bg,
                                filled: true,
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none, borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(getMyWidth(5)))),
                              ),
                              style: makeBlackStyle(),
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                              maxLines: null,
                              cursorColor: themeColor,
                              onChanged: (str) {
                                setState(() {
                                  inputStr = str;
                                });
                              },
                            )
```

so, my question is: How to set the default height of the textfield when there is no word?   I want to decrease the default height of the textfiled , and need support mulitiline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with following to have ***at-least 3*** lines in your TextField:

```
TextField(
  minLines: 3,
  controller: _textEditingController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "留下你的评论吧~",
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: getMyWidth(10), right: getMyWidth(10)),
    fillColor: default_bg,
    filled: true,
    border: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none, borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(getMyWidth(5)))),
  ),
  style: makeBlackStyle(),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: null,
  cursorColor: themeColor,
  onChanged: (str) {
    setState(() {
      inputStr = str;
    });
  },
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'minLines: 2', it will give you the height of the number of lines you put. 
Hope it help.

Comment: I want change the padding of word and the outlineBorder.

Comment: i want make the height of the textfiled smaller and support multiline

Comment: you confused. What exactly do you want ? Increase the padding of the textfield ?

Comment: @OMiShah decrease the height of the textfiled , but need support mulitiline

Comment: you can set ``maxLines: 5`` or to whatever you height want. IT will support multiline still.

Answer (score 2):

just set isDense : true in decoration

Comment: and using minHeight

Answer (score 0):

Use can set `maxLines` of the `TextField` to set max height. Setting maxLines will still support multiline.

```
TextField(
maxLines: 5
)
```

Comment: I want to decrease the default height of the textfiled , and need support mulitiline

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27838

accepted aswer
Use -> contentPadding:

```
TextField(
decoration: InputDecoration(
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),//here  set your padding
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27838#issuecomment-507603179
```

or

```
new Container(
width:80.0
child:new TextField
)
```

Comment: I want to decrease the height of the textfiled , but need support mulitiline,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following, which I am using in one my projects as well. Wrap your `TextField` in a container and change the size of the container itself. Then add a `contentPadding` to make the input smaller.

```
Container(
    height 56, // Optional to decrease/increase
    child: TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0), // Increase to make smaller
        prefixIcon: icon,
        labelText: 'Label',
        hintText: 'Hint',
        border: null,
    ),
    minLines: 1,
    maxLines: null // Adds support for multiple lines
));
```

Comment: but the height of the textfiled has been fixed,  I want to make the height of textfiled can increase by the lines.

Comment: You can add `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),` to the `InputDecoration`.

Answer (score 0):

set in `TextField`

- `minLines`: NUMBER, // default: 1
- `maxLines`: NUMBER or null, // null: support for multiple lines

set in `decoration`

- `isDense` : true // uses less vertical space, default: false

Hope to help you